# Flutter - PageController error: `Page value is only available after content dimensions are established.`

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to animate some widgets inside PageView and created a custom AnimatedWidget which uses PageController also used by PageView. The idea is to animate some text up as user swipes through slides. The code below will throw error on the first render, once I start swiping left/right everything works but I get red screen with error initially. I tried to defend by checking controller.hasClients but there is already 1 page in the controller and error comes from assertion in PageView page getter.
Is there any other prop I can check to delay animating after the first render?

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MySlider extends StatelessWidget {
  final _controller = new PageController();

  final List<String> _pages = [
    'Create your football profile',
    'Your team, your players, your line-up',
    'Track the stats that matter and share with others'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          PageView.builder(
            controller: _controller,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) => Slide(
              controller: _controller,
              position: index,
              heading: _pages[index],
            ),
            itemCount: _pages.length,
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          ),
        ]
      )
    );
  }
}

class Slide extends AnimatedWidget {

  final PageController controller;
  final String heading;
  final int position;

  Slide({
    this.controller,
    this.heading,
    this.position
  }) : super(listenable: controller);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final textYOffset = controller.hasClients
        ? screenHeight * (controller.page - position)
        : 0;

    final opacity = controller.hasClients
        ? 1.0 - math.max(0, controller.page - position)
        : 1.0;

    return Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        children: [
          Positioned(
              bottom: 120,
              left: 16,
              right: 16,
              child: Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset(0, -textYOffset),
                  child: Opacity(
                      opacity: opacity,
                      child: Text(heading)
                  ),
              ),
          )
        ],
    );
  }
}
```

Exception in the console:

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library   ═════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> The following assertion was thrown building Slide(animation:
>
> PageController#c35ec(one client, offset 0.0), dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _AnimatedState#05ff4):
>
> Page value is only available after content dimensions are established.
>   'package:flutter/src/widgets/page_view.dart':
>
> Failed assertion: line 373 pos 7: 'pixels == null || (minScrollExtent != null &&maxScrollExtent != null)'

`minScrollExtent` at this point is 0.0 same with `maxScrollExtent`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taking into account the way you implemented the slide and the error you are getting about the content dimensions not being available a possible, but I think ugly, solution would be to check if the dimensions are available before trying to use the controller:

```
if(controller.position.haveDimensions){
  final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  final textYOffset = controller.hasClients
      ? screenHeight * (controller.page - position)
      : 0;

  final opacity = controller.hasClients
      ? 1.0 - math.max(0, controller.page - position)
      : 1.0;

  return Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    children: [
      Positioned(
        bottom: 120,
        left: 16,
        right: 16,
        child: Transform.translate(
          offset: Offset(0, -textYOffset),
          child: Opacity(
              opacity: opacity,
              child: Text(heading)
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  );
} else {
  return SizedBox();
}
```

Despite this "fixing" the error you get displayed, you still have an error on the last page, regardless of my changes. There might be a better implementation of the animation you want to have, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Hey João, Thanks for answering my question, your solution works fine. I don't see any error sliding to the last page I always render the same widget tree and use fallback animation values if I can't calc correctly. Do you have a suggestion about what would be a better way to implement this type of animation, some hints or links I could read? I'm new to Flutter and your comment suggest this may not be a good way to do it.

Comment: @Mahakala Not at the moment, sorry. I will experiment with it when I have time. If my answer fixed your issue, please remember to mark it as correct to help future users. Good luck with your app!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Good luck with your app!